# On a metric space $(X,d)$, is every equivalent metric $d'$ dependent on $d$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a given metric space. If $d'$ is another metric on $X$ which is equivalent to $d$, it it true that $d'$ will depend on $d$?

I think, $d'$ has to be dependent on $d$, otherwise there would not be difference between metric space and metrizable space.

Comment: Do you know something like $d'(x, y) = f(d(x, y))$ for some $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Consider some examples of equivalent metrics on $\mathbb R^2$.  The usual metric and, say, the sup metric $$d((x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)) = \max\{ |x_1-y_1|, |x_2-y_2|\}$$

Comment: @D_S  $\max\{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|\}=\max\{\big(\|u-v\|_2^2-(x_2-y_2)^2\big)^{1/2}, \big(\|u-v\|_2^2-(x_1-y_1)^2\big)^{1/2}\}$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes usual metric on $\mathbb R^2$, $u=(x_1,x_2), v=(y_1,y_2).$

Comment: @ArcticChar I did not mean that every function of $d$ is a metric, I mean a new equivalent metric $d'$ is a function of $d$ i.e. $d'$ is dependent on $d$.

Comment: Infinite - "depend on $d$" isn't very precise mathematical language, and I think @ArcticChar was trying to clarify what you meant. I assume they intended to write "Do you mean something like ..", which is what I assumed you meant (and based my answer on). If you mean something different, please specify it explicitly in your question.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC   `` $f$ is a function of $x$ '' is equivalent to `` $f$ is dependent on $x$ ''. Here $x$ is dependent variable  and $f(x)$ is independent variable. We have seen these terms 'dependent', `independent' in calculus. Is not it so?

Comment: @jonathanz thanks, thats exactly what i meant.

Comment: Infinite - In your response to D_S you have written d' in terms of d __and__ the original points. If that's what you mean by "depend on" then every variable $a$ is dependent on any variable $b$, because $a = (b+a) - b$.

Answer (score 4):

The question has already been answered, but I thought I'd add a simple counterexample. Take $X=\{1,2,3\}$ with the following two metrics:
\begin{align*}
 d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=y \\ 1 & x \neq y\end{cases}&& && d'(x,y)=|x-y|
\end{align*}
Those two metrics are equivalent (actually any two metrics on a finite set are equivalent). However you can't write $d'$ as a function of $d$ because $d(1,2)=d(1,3)$ and $d'(1,2) \neq d'(1,3)$.

Comment: \begin{align*}
 d'(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=y \\ |x-y| & x \neq y\end{cases}&& && =\begin{cases} 0  & x=y \\ |x-y| d(x,y) & x \neq y\end{cases}
\end{align*} i.e. $d'(x,y)=|x-y| d(x,y).$

Comment: I think writing $d'(x,y) = d'(x,y) d(x,y)$ (which is exactly what you have done in your comment) is really more about expressing $d'$ in terms of $d'$ itself, than it is about expressing $d'$ in terms of $d$. If you allow things like what you wrote, then why not just write $d'(x,y) =d'(x,y) + d(x,y) - d(x,y)$ in the general case then? It seems like you need to think more about what exactly you mean by "$d'$ will depend on $d$".

Comment: Yes, the OP really needs to clarify what they mean by "depend". A good start would be to respond to ArcticChar's question in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

No. Your condition would say that if $d(x_1, y_1) = d(x_2, y_2)$ then  $d'(x_1, y_1) = d'(x_2, y_2)$. And it's pretty easy to construct equivalent metrics that violate that.

@D_S gives a nice example in their comment, comparing the standard and sup metrics on $\mathbb R^2$.

Me, I'd like to construct one by defining $d'(x, y) = d(x, y) * f(x)$, where $f$ is a non-constant, continuous function of $x$ that "stays near $1$", i.e. just scaling your original metric by a factor that varies based on $x$. But that's just a suggestion that could get stuck on some detail.

Comment: Is d' a metric?

Comment: Hmm, good question. Updated to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

On $\Bbb R^2$ the metrics $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2}$, $d_1(x,y)= |x_1-y_1|+ |x_2-y_2|$ and $d_\infty(x,y)=\max(|x_1-y_1|, |x_2-y_2|)$ are all equivalent. How do they "depend" on each other?